# Submodules not checking out correctly on windows

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on github:

`git@github.com:daviddoria/InteractiveImageGraphCutSegmentation.git`

It has several submodules. When I clone it (on linux) and then do `'git submodule update --init --recursive'`, everything works fine.

However, a friend of mine on windows gets an error:

```
"fatal: Not a git repository: ../../../../..//d/Repo/InteractiveImageGraphCutSegm" .
```

Does anyone know what would cause that? I tried changing the submodule URLs (in `.gitmodules`) to all of the different protocols, but the errors persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a actually a bug in msysgit. I believe it has been fixed in master.

Answer (score 1):

Path not correct? So many levels of "../".  This cannot exist in github.